# How to create an Android Studio build script to insert git commit hash in build version?

Tags: android-manifest, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to insert the hash of the last git commit inside my AndroidManifest (more specificaly the versionCode tag).

I am using gradle with Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this post](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/07/30/automatic-versioning-with-git-and-gradle/) by Ryan Harter, tag your commit and add the following to your build.gradle script.

```
/*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */
def getVersionName = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Then change the `versionName` in `defaultConfig` to use `getVersionName()`.

Comment: Hi, I know this post is pretty old, but I was wondering if there is a way to add the git commit date with this? So that you have the commit hash + commit date. Thanks!

Comment: @mohammed_sajid You could use `git show -s --format='%ai'` to produce the commit date, or `git show -s --format='%H %ai'` to produce the hash and the date. There are many other date formats and options. See `git help show`.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the OQ, add the following to the android section of the app's build.gradle

```
def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Since versionCode is numeric, then change defaultConfig versionName to

```
versionName getGitHash()
```

**Better Implementation**

What I actually do with my own project is to inject the value into a BuildConfig variable and access it that way.

I use these methods in the android section:

```
def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
}

def getGitBranch = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
}
```

and add this to the BuildConfig section:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_HASH", getGitHash()
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_BRANCH", getGitBranch()
        ...
    }
 }
```

Then in source code, such as Application.java

```
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "git branch=" + BuildConfig.GIT_BRANCH);
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "git commit=" + BuildConfig.GIT_HASH);
```

Comment: Retrieving the Git branch is better done using `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`, which retrieves the branch name if you are at the HEAD of one, and otherwise returns nothing. In the latter case `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` returns `HEAD`. For something more symbolically descriptive of the commit, you can also try `git name-rev --name-only HEAD`.