# Storing Current Git Hash in App When Compiling

Tags: android, git, android-gradle-plugin

Years ago I was looking for a way to add our current git hash to our Android app (built on Java). I found this wonderful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380672/516561

---

**My Code is Below**

I basically copied their code for my own project, but essentially I put the following function in my app build.gradle:

```
def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine "git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD"
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Then in my default config, I put the following:

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  buildConfigField "String", "GitHash", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
  ...
```

Then in my Java Code, I can reference the Git Hash as follows:

```
BuildConfig.GitHash
```

---

This has worked flawlessly for a long time. But unfortunately, starting upgrading from Gradle plugin 8.1.4 to 8.2.2 now gives me the following error:

`Starting an external process 'git rev-parse --short HEAD' during configuration time is unsupported.`

**So my question is as follows:**

Am I doing something wrong in the upgrade that is just causing this to fail? Or is there something I need to change in the way I am getting the hash starting with 8.2.2?

I did not see anything that made the commandLine execs not deprecated. Maybe I am overlooking something simple??

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: May be there is a gradle plugin that can read the commit hash directly by using JGit and thus does not require to execute an external command?